# addEventListener on many dynamic inputs return always target for first input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add event listener on dynamically generated switch buttons. Each button in different table row.

It works fine when there is only one switch button on page, but when there are 2 and I click on second, for some reason event Target is still coming like from the first button.

Below function returnы always first target on the page, not the one which was clicked.

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
// Do some check on target
if ( evt.target.classList.contains('onoffswitch-checkbox') ) {
    // DO CODE
    var target = evt;
    console.log(target)
    console.log(target.path[2]);
  }
}, true); // Use Capturing
```

Appreciate your ideas how to avoid such scenario. 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because you are attaching the click event to the body-element?

Comment: Can we see some HTML so we can recreate it? Are you sure the buttons do not have the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked you code in jsfiddle, I changed first console.log to show which element I clicked and it shows directly which span I clicked

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
// Do some check on target
if ( evt.target.classList.contains('onoffswitch-checkbox') ) {
    // DO CODE
    var target = evt;
    console.log(target.toElement)
    console.log(target.path[2]);
  }
}, true); // Use Capturing
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0afef0Ln/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your tags say jQuery, so how about something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.onoffswitch-checkbox', function(event) {
   console.log(this)
});
```

It should take the dynamically generated input into account

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted @Jorg. This would be the correct jquery way return the clicked control.